# See every post and get requests outgoing from my computer using C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, networking

As part of my application I need to see and control every post and get requests outgoing from my computer (like in fiddler). Can I do it using C#, what classes should I use? If C# doesn't have these features maybe someone know libraries for C++ (C# is preferable) with which I can do it.

Comment: [Why reinvent the wheel?](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: I need this functionality for my app, it's not main part of application.

Comment: Good info to add to your question. Recommend an edit to include it. Never tried to do this myself, but you should be able to use [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968803.aspx) or hang off of [winpcap's API](https://www.winpcap.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for this task. If somebody is interested, for C++ it's [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) library and for .Net it's a wrapper for WinPcap [Pcap.Net](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net) library. Thank you @user4581301.